# Is there a word for a deictic pun?

Tags: single-word-requests

As Charles Fillmore showed, deictic ambiguities abound, but some jokes are based upon them. There's Fillmore's own, "I read War and Peace while she talked to her mother on the phone," and with apologies to Fillmore there is Hannibal Lector's,  "I'm having an old friend for dinner." In terms of the dreaded SAT exams, my question is  "Pun : Conundrum :: a-joke-based-on-deictic-ambiguity : ______.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a source to explain what deictic puns are? Also, [tag:single-word-requests] require an example sentence in which the word could be used.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: [**Bob is the man to the left of Mark** - where Bob may be to Mark's own left (non-deictic), or to the left from the speaker's point of view (deictic).](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mark%27s+own+left+non-deictic%22)

Comment: @Bla Maybe I don't understand the idea of deictic. The sentence about the phone conversation is from the speaker's viewpoint and so can mean that he read all of War and Peace while she was on the phone. An onlooker might interpret the sentence to mean the speaker was reading War and Peace while she was on the phone. Similarly Lector's statement is from his point of view and so does not mean what you and I would mean by the same sentence. Feel free to fix my question by supplying the correct word for "dealing with the conceptual center" and take off points, but I hope you allow the question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought about using "conceptual" in room of "deictic," but what I have in mind is sharper than that. "We have the finest congress money can buy" is conceptual. But the War-and-Peace joke is not just a concept; it hinges on the way we are forced take the speaker's position.

Comment: deixis (/ˈdaɪksᵻs/)[1] refers to words and phrases, such as “me” or “here”, that cannot be fully understood without additional contextual information -- in this case, the identity of the speaker (“me”) and the speaker's location (“here”). Words are deictic if their semantic meaning is fixed but their denotational meaning varies depending on time and/or place. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis

Comment: @Airymouse: I don't really see how the War-and-Peace joke forces us to take the speaker's position. All it hinges on is whether we understand ***read*** as applying to ***some pages*** or ***the whole book***. But I'm having trouble coming up with anything you could reasonably call a "pun" which *doesn't* effectively depend on deixis (expressions having multiple meanings where only context tells us which applies, except that in the case of a pun we very specifically *allow* those multiple meanings to "exist").

Comment: I'm about to have a friend for dinner. (Really.)When we are done, I'll rethink things. Your point is that any pun relies on deixis and that Fillmore's joke can be thought of as a pun on "read." Similarly, Lector's line is a pun on "having." Maybe I want a distinction that does not exist.

Comment: [Have a look at Fillmore](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), then. I don't know whether it harbors puns, but it certainly has some lovely jokes. For instance, [English is not yet ready to describe flounders.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/flounder.html)

Comment: @John Lawler I did look at Fillmore and I'm about to admit to Bladorthin   that the joke I took from Fillmore  is a pun on "read." Your link to Fillmore is deemed safe by Norton, whereas several others are not. My wife just got a special issue of Duke Magazine,Say What? The Language Issue. I think they got the idea for their title from Fillmore, but then I went to Chapel Hill. Duke used lots of tapioca, so the issue is much slicker than your photocopy of the Deixis Lectures. Content is another matter.. By some fluke, I read his discussion of flounders a few days ago and nearly flipped.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are right: I am trying to make a distinction that isn't there. The hardest thing to explain is a mistake, but let me try. If Fillmore had said, "I read War and Peace while she fixed dinner,"  you would not think he had read the whole book. So the joke hinges not only on a play on the word, "read", but on the  context as well. My mistake, which you have pointed out, is that this is true of all puns. I'd have a case that "the name of the song is called haddocks' eyes." is a context-free joke. Alice misconstrues "name" and "called," but I admit these words are not puns.